# Exibir dinamicamente o registro do banco de dados com a respectiva categoria

Tags: php, html, mysql

Tenho esse código html que separa as os registros do banco de dados de acordo com a categoria.

```
<div class="example1">
  <h1>Painel do Cliente</h1>
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading" data-acc-link="demo1"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contabilidade</div>
      <div class="panel-body acc-open" data-acc-content="demo1">

        <div class="col-lg-4 pdf">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsium Lostes dewla</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 pdf">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsium Lostes dewla</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 pdf">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsium Lostes dewla</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 pdf">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsium Lostes dewla</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 pdf">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsium Lostes dewla</h4>
        </div>


       <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:40px;"></div> 

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading" data-acc-link="demo2"><i class="fa fa-id-card" aria-hidden="true"></i> Setor Pessoal</div>
      <div class="panel-body" data-acc-content="demo2">
       <div class="col-lg-6 pdf">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsium Lostes dewla</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 pdf">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsium Lostes dewla</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 pdf">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsium Lostes dewla</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 pdf">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsium Lostes dewla</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 pdf">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsium Lostes dewla</h4>
        </div>
      <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:40px;"></div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Quero que o PHP busque no banco de dados e separe por categoria como no exemplo Html, estou usando o **INNER JOIN do PHP/Mysql**, mais não está certo, fica as divs ficam em cima da outra

```
<div class="example1">
          <h1 class="pseudo_border_titulo">Painel do Cliente</h1>




    <?php

echo $idUsuario;                                                  
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root','xx', 'xx');

$sql = "SELECT categoria.id AS id_categoria, categoria.nome AS nome_categoria, categoria.pt AS pt_categoria, categoria.url AS url_categoria,
aruivos_clientes.id_usuario AS id_usuario, aruivos_clientes.nome_arquivo AS nome_arquivo, aruivos_clientes.id_categoria_arquivos AS id_categoria_arquivos, aruivos_clientes.data AS data
FROM categoria
INNER JOIN aruivos_clientes
ON categoria.id = aruivos_clientes.id_categoria_arquivos AND aruivos_clientes.id_usuario=$idUsuario 
ORDER BY nome_categoria, data";

$query = $mysqli->query( $sql )or die( $mysqli->error );

$prev_cat = '';
$nome_categ = array();
while( $dados = $query->fetch_object() )
{


if( $prev_cat!=$dados->nome_categoria )
{







$i_check++;
?>
<div class="panel panel-primary">   

<div class="panel-heading" data-acc-link="demo1"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> <?php echo ''.utf8_encode($dados->nome_categoria).' ';?>
</div>
    <div class="panel-body acc-open" data-acc-content="demo1">                 

<?php 
$prev_cat = $dados->nome_categoria;
}

?>

<div class="col-lg-4 pdf">
<h4><?php echo utf8_encode($dados->nome_arquivo); ?></h4>
</div>        


<?php


 }   ?>
        </div>      
  <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:40px;"></div>         
    </div>
```

Comment: Wagner, pode esclarecer o motivo de ter revertido a edição que adicionou a tag `html`, sendo que, dada as informações da pergunta, o problema está no HTML?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="example1">
    <h1 class="pseudo_border_titulo">Painel do Cliente</h1>


    <div class="panel panel-primary">

    <?php echo $idUsuario; $mysqli=n ew mysqli( 'localhost', 'root', 'xx', 'xx'); $sql="SELECT categoria.id AS id_categoria, categoria.nome AS nome_categoria, categoria.pt AS pt_categoria, categoria.url AS url_categoria,
    aruivos_clientes.id_usuario AS id_usuario, aruivos_clientes.nome_arquivo AS nome_arquivo, aruivos_clientes.id_categoria_arquivos AS id_categoria_arquivos, aruivos_clientes.data AS data
    FROM categoria
    INNER JOIN aruivos_clientes
    ON categoria.id = aruivos_clientes.id_categoria_arquivos AND aruivos_clientes.id_usuario=$idUsuario 
    ORDER BY nome_categoria, data" ; $query=$ mysqli->query( $sql )or die( $mysqli->error ); $prev_cat = ''; $nome_categ = array(); while( $dados = $query->fetch_object() ) { if( $prev_cat!=$dados->nome_categoria ) { if( $prev_cat!='' ) $i_check++; ?>

        <div class="panel-heading" data-acc-link="demo1"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <?php echo ''.utf8_encode($dados->nome_categoria).' ';?>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body acc-open" data-acc-content="demo1">

            <?php $prev_cat=$ dados->nome_categoria; } ?>

            <div class="col-lg-4 pdf">
                <h4><?php echo utf8_encode($dados->nome_arquivo); ?></h4>


            </div>
        </div>

        <?php } ?>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: assim não ficará como na estrutura html que mencionei <div class="panel panel-primary">...</div>

Comment: Você precisa ajustar as div's dentro do seu loop, ok? imagine que a cada laço executado suas divs são um bloco e esse bloco precisa saber quando quebrar automaticamente.

Quem sabe se você utilizar um <div style=`display:block`> ???

Comment: Desculpe amigo, nao notei que seu <div class="panel panel-primary"> está dentro do loop, tente colocar antes do loop e faça um teste.

Comment: isso mesmo tem um loop ali, nao deu certo tbm, ficouu desajustado